# hibernate get twice object from database within one transaction

Tags: sql, hibernate

I have the next test:

```
public void testAddDonations() throws MalformedURLException, SQLException, DatabaseUnitException {
        prepareCategoriesAndProjects();
        Project proj = (Project) session.get(Project.class, 1);
        Project proj2 = (Project) session.get(Project.class, 2);
        DonationLogic donation = new DonationLogic(10000,50);
        donation.setProject(proj);
        DonationLogic donation2 = new DonationLogic(100000,500);
        donation2.setProject(proj2);

        session.persist(donation);
        session.persist(donation2);
        session.flush();
        Project proj3 = (Project) session.get(Project.class, 2);
        assertEquals(100000, proj3.getDonation());
}
```

My problem here is when I load at first *proj2* from database **getDonation** is *null* (no enties are in *donations* table yet). However when I try to load from database *proj3* (the same as *proj2*), hibernate does not go to database and **getDonation** is still *null*. More - tests show that proj2 and proj3 for hibernate is one object. So hibernate does not go to database second time (i think beacuse it thinks it already has object *proj2*). Can I change this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

This is the way Hibernate first level cache works. If entities are found in the first level cache, they are not re-read from the database.

To achieve what you want you could:

1) [Clear](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#clear%28%29) the session after flushing:

```
session.flush();
session.clear();
```

This way first level cache will be emptied and entities are re-read from the database when requested.

2) [Refresh](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#refresh%28java.lang.Object%29) the entity:

```
session.refresh(proj2);
```

This way `proj2` is refreshed with the current state from the database (affects `proj3` also because it's the same object).

3) And the last, but the **best and recommended** solution, update both sides of bidirectional associations whenever possible:

```
donation2.setProject(proj2);
proj2.setDonationLogic(donation2);
```